# How To Populate PDF With Values From Model

Tags: python, django, pdf

My django project generates a view in the form of a PDF file which uses an HTML file to outline the format.  I have a separate view which simply displays a drop down list of all the "Reference IDs" in my "Orders" model.  My goal is to choose a "Reference ID" from the dropdown, click submit, and have the PDF generate populating certain values with values from the data that corresponds to that reference ID in the Orders model.

For example, I'd like to

What I have is listed below - any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Below shows code for the view generating the dropdown:

VIEWS.PY

```
def reference_view(request):
    query_results = Orders.objects.all()
    reference_list = DropDownMenuReferences()

    context = {
        'query_results': query_results,
        'reference_list': reference_list
    }
    return render(request, 'proforma_select.html', context)
```

FORMS.PY

```
class DropDownMenuReferences(forms.Form):
    Reference_IDs = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Orders.objects.values_list('reference', flat=True).distinct(),
    empty_label=None)
```

Proforma_select.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container">

  <br>

  <form method=POST action="">
    {{ reference_list }}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button">Add Order</button>
  </form>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Below shows code for the PDF which is generated:

VIEWS.PY

```
def generate_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    template = get_template('invoice.html')
    context = {
        "invoice_id": 123,
        "ultimate_consignee": "john cooper",

    }
    html = template.render(context)
    pdf = render_to_pdf('invoice.html', context)
    return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

INVOICE.HTML (only way I could find online to do this was with HTML 4)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Proforma Invoice</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-weight: 200;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            .header {
                font-size: 20px;
                font-weight: 100;
                text-align: center;
                color: #007cae;
            }
            .title {
                font-size: 22px;
                font-weight: 100;
               /* text-align: right;*/
               padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
            }
            .title span {
                color: #007cae;
            }
            .details {
                padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
                text-align: left !important;
                /*margin-left: 40%;*/
            }
            .hrItem {
                border: none;
                height: 1px;
                /* Set the hr color */
                color: #333; /* old IE */
                background-color: #fff; /* Modern Browsers */
            }
            .column {
              float: left;
              width: 50%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class='header'>
                <p class='title'>Proforma Invoice # {{ invoice_id }}</p>
                <p class='title'>Customer: {{ ultimate_consignee }}</p>
            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Below is the MODELS.PY for Orders Model which the dropdown menu reference IDs is created from and where I would like to pull other fields into the PDF:

MODELS.PY

```
class Orders(models.Model):

    reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    ultimate_consignee = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    ship_to = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    vessel = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    booking_no = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    POL = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    DOL = models.DateField()
    COO = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    POE = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ETA = models.DateField()
    pickup_no = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    terms = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    sales_contact = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    trucking_co = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    loading_loc = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    inspector = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    total_cases = models.IntegerField()
    total_fob = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    freight_forwarder = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    commodity = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_airshipment = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    credit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

def _str_(self):
    return self.reference
```

As you can see - I am current hardcoding in values to the View which then appear on the PDF - but I'd like these to pull from the Orders Model.

i.e. something like WHERE Reference ID = 100, Ultimate Consignee = John Smith

Answer (score 0):

You have to improve your code with a couple of changes

**First**

Your form is not pointing to any action (Maybe you are using Js for activating the view that generates the PDF) and the easiest way to delivering the form data to the view is making the form `action` attribute points to the target view.

Let's say your view has an URL named **generate_pdf** (see [Naming URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)) then you could in your template:

```
 <form method=POST action="{% url generate_pdf %}">
    {{ reference_list }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button">Add Order</button>
 </form>
```

**Second**

... having the form pointing to your view, you can read the `Reference_IDs` from the post data in order to obtain the `Order` instance and use it:

```
def generate_view(request, *args, **kwargs):

    context = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        order_reference = self.request.POST.get('Reference_IDs')
        if order_reference is not None:
            order = Orders.objects.get(reference=order_reference)
            template = get_template('invoice.html')
            context.update({
                "ultimate_consignee": order.ultimate_consignee,
                # ... 
            })
            html = template.render(context)
    pdf = render_to_pdf('invoice.html', context)
    return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

Good luck!

*Note: I've not tested this, it is just an effort to show you one of the approaches you can follow to achieve what you want.*

Comment: Thank you for the input - I tried the above and replaced with the correct url in action attribute of the form, but I am getting a NoReverseMatch error and I'm not sure why....

Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

this happens when I try to go to display the form now that I've added the url to the action.  any thoughts?